# Flask Error with wsgi_handler

Tags: python, iis, flask, fastcgi

I am trying to use WSGI on Windows Server to run a simple flask app.  I keep running into the following error:

> Error occurred while reading WSGI handler: Traceback (most recent call
>   last): File "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test_site\wfastcgi.py", line 711, in
>   main env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path) File
>   "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test_site\wfastcgi.py", line 568, in
>   read_wsgi_handler return env, get_wsgi_handler(handler_name) File
>   "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test_site\wfastcgi.py", line 551, in
>   get_wsgi_handler raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported' %
>   handler_name) ValueError: "app.app" could not be imported StdOut:
>   StdErr

For my site I configured a handler to call the FastCGIModule from Microsoft Web Platform installer

My app file looks as such:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from analyzers import analyzer
import write_log

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def test():
    return "Test load"

@app.route('/analyze', methods=['POST'])
def parse():
    text = request.json['text']
    name = request.json['name']
    model = request.json['model']
    try:
        convert_flag = request.json['convert_flag']
    except KeyError:
        convert_flag = False
    results= analyzer(text, name, model, convert_dose=convert_flag)
    write_log.write_log(text, name, model, results)
    return jsonify(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

If I comment out the custom import of my analyzer script and my write_log script along with the POST method things will run, so I know I must be messing something up there.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Paul

Comment: were you able to get an answer to this question? thanks

Comment: @labheshr Sorry I was not.  Never was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the problem was with a third-party library. What's causing your problem is certainly something different, but here's something I did to identify my issue and may help you as well:

1. Open wfastcgi.py
2. Locate the method `get_wsgi_handler` (probably on line 519)
3. There's a `try/except` inside a `while module_name` statement
4. Add `raise` to the end of the `except` block and save the file, like this:

   ```
   except ImportError:
       ...
       raise
   ```
5. Access your website URL again and check your logs, they now should be more detailed about what caused the `ImportError` and will point you in the right direction to fix the issue